# Generating non isomorphic graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

Is it possible to generate all non isomorphic graphs of given order (small) and size with Mathematica (and IGraph?)?  I don’t immediately see how to do that, and if this is not possible without complicated programming and use of IGIsomorphicQ, this would be a nice to have, especially if additional constraints can be chosen, such as connectivity, min-degree, etc.  There are in general too many non isomorphic graphs to list them all, even for small orders, but being able to list them all when additional restrictions are given is very desirable ...

Comment: Not sure if it will help but you might want to check [this fairly recent article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11786-019-00397-5?wt_mc=alerts.TOCjournals&utm_source=toc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=toc_11786_13_4) on graph symmetry breaking.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `geng` from the nauty suite can handle this problem very well. The only issue is that Mathematica's Graph6 importer is not as good as it could be (despite years of asking for improvements). The next version of IGraph/M will have a better/faster Graph6 importer, but unfortunately it will still be limited by the construction speed of `Graph` expressions (which is pretty slow...)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau By the way Daniel, FindVertexCut is broken, the developers are aware of it.  Hopefully this gets fixed fast, it is a fundamental function, and the only way to test connectivity right now in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

The nauty tool includes the program `geng` which can generate all non-isomorphic graphs with various constraints (including on the number of vertices, edges, connectivity, biconnectivity, triangle-free and others). Its output is in the Graph6 format, which Mathematica can import.

For example, assuming you have `geng` installed in `/opt/local/bin`,

```
Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng 4", "Graph6"]
```

[image]

There are typically a *very* large number of results, and `geng` is likely the fastest tool for the exhaustive generation of non-isomorphic graphs. The bottleneck when using it with Mathematica is not `geng` itself, but Mathematica's importer.

The *next* (yet unreleased) version of IGraph/M will include a faster Graph6 importer than Mathematica's built-in, as well as a Digraph6 importer for directed graphs (not currently supported by Mathematica).

```
In[9]:= Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng 8", "Graph6"]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[9]= {3.17038, Null}

In[10]:= IGImport["!/opt/local/bin/geng 8", "Graph6"]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[10]= {0.853189, Null}
```

I considered integrating `geng` into IGraph/M, but there would be little benefit compared to calling `geng` as a separate process. Converting to Mathematica's graph format would be just as slow as with `IGImport`. Thus I decided to focus on a fast and flexible Graph6/Sparse6/Digraph6 importer instead. Many graph theory tools use these formats, so it is very useful to be able to handle them well (better than Mathematica currently can).

Comment: Thanks!  Looking forward to these developments. Is there anything in the works to extend matchings to a maximum matching? Getting them one by one starting from an arbitrary one in lex order ... Connectivity? Perhaps the wrong place to ask, but how can I post about what is not there?

Comment: @EGME For IGraph/M specifically, there is https://gitter.im/IGraphM/Lobby  For igraph more generally, there's the mailing list: https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/igraph-help We plan to launch a modern support forum early next year.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a long wish list ... indeed there is much room for new and improved functionality, wherever it comes from ...

Comment: When you get already to order 10, there are millions of non isomorphic graphs.  Is it possible to get them with geng one by one, from say, a certain index, in the order they are given, to another one?  As in many of my problems, I need to avoid cramming memory ... but I can afford to check things one by one, in phases .... check the post for NextKSizePartition ...

Comment: @EGME I am not sure. `geng` is a command line program that writes to the standard output. Its output can be pipes to another process (common with the nauty tools, actually) and it can also be read incrementally. It is possible to read the graphs one by one with Mathematica. However, I do not think that doing this will stop `geng` from going on with the graph generation in the background. I am also not sure where the OS stores all that intermediate piped data (in memory or on disk).

Comment: @EGME If you ask another question, I can try to figure out how exactly to read `geng`'s output incrementally and post an answer.

Comment: Thanks ... I will post it ... I need a bit of time, I still have a busy eve here, maybe it will be there tomorrow .. I will alert you to it.

Comment: I posted the question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211290/53849 ... thanks!